# Can a quartz vanity countertop be recut for a larger sink?

Tags: cutting, countertops, quartz

I currently have a 55x19 quartz countertop that has a small undermount sink. If I decide to reuse the countertop for a larger drop in sink could it be recut by a pro shop? What is the probability that this might crack (due to narrow margins left when the new cut is created)

Comment: 1. I'd assume, but that's a question for the shop. 2. Depends on the care given by your chosen shop and the installer. These answers seem fairly obvious. Is there a reason you're asking us before you ask the shop?

Comment: 1. I will need to find that shop. 2 I have no knowledge about cutting countertops and I might wast time founding a shop if the answer is obvious and it is NO for reasons unknown to me but knows to those with much more experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the unit to a granite shop and the shop will provide you with an answer like this.

"While it is possible to cut some quartz it is not a guarantee that it will cut properly. The possibility exist that the quartz will break or chip during the cutting process."

So if you are set on cutting it out - have it done .. and take the chance - if it does not work - buy a granite scrap piece.

Good luck..

Comment: From your answer I take it that some quartz varieties can be re-cut while some can't? What are the particularities for those that can't ?
What am I supposed to do with the scrap piece ?

Comment: @MiniMe  the scrap piece ken refers to is a remnant of granite you may find at the shop. Theses can be purchased much cheaper than selecting from full slabs

Comment: How would that help if I have quartz counter top and there is a very small chance they will match the same finish that I have ..

Comment: @MiniMe you are correct some can be and some can't I do not do it professionally so I do not have specifics other than what my local granite shops told me. Engineered quartz is the most difficult to know as the manufacturing process varies along with the materials used. So basically they said it was a crap shoot for me I just wanted to know (before I bought my top) if I could have a 60 shortened to 54. A straight cut and that discouraged me from making that investment and attempt.

Comment: @MiniMe How will that help if there is a small chance they could match the finish you already have. I hate to say it this way but I can't think of another way to put it .. if your quartz top gets broken by the attempt to cut it - the chance you will put your broken quartz top back in will be smaller than the chance of you finding something to replace it with. So you might want to just take a peek at those scraps while you are getting the company to try to cut your quartz top.

Comment: is so happens that the quartz that I have in the bathroom is the same with the one in the kitchen so no breaking that is not an option. Not sure how much it will cost but I will have to pay 400CAD for a sink integrated in a countertop (white modern look, ceramic) it will cost me half that to have the quartz cut and more for a brand new 55"x19" piece of quartz

Comment: @MiniMe - I understand .. If it were me in that situation - either way I am changing it out. I think I would try the cheaper cut route - see if they can do it. The worst is I am out the attempted savings by cutting money - that is the worst - so maybe 100 , that is basically what it will cost to find out if you need to spend 400 or can get a way with the cheaper route of say 100 - worth a shot much to save if it works.